# when i add 'session' code, the page is not working

Tags: php

it's simple authentification
but i don't know why session interrupt the page,
when i click on submit 
'the page connect.php is interrupt'
'Unable to process this request'
'HTTP ERROR 500'

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];   

    $portfolio = new vendor\Model\portfolio();
    $list_portfolio = $portfolio->select_portfolio_by_mail($mail,$pwd);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($list_portfolio[2],MYSQL_ASSOC);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nom'] = $result['nom'];
    $_SESSION['prenom'] = $result['prenom'];
```

index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['nom']))
{ 
echo $contenu_fr; 
}
elseif (!isset ($_SESSION['nom']))
 { ?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $url_front.'/control/connect.php' ?>" id="contactForm">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="login" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" value="" id="name" required/>
 </div>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
 <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe"
 value="" id="email" required/>
 </div>
 </div>

<div class="row right">
<div class="col-md-12  col-sm-12  col-xs-2 foot">
 <input type="submit" value="LOG IN" id="submit"/>
</div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If that's all the code, you don't close the `elseif`.

Comment: Look at your server's error log and it will tell you which line is throwing the fatal error. As Jon Stirling says, it looks like you didn't close the else if.

Comment: i close the the elseif (i took just a part of my code )
the problem in the first code (php) it causes the interruption

Comment: Add the output from your server's error log to help us identify where the error is being thrown from

Answer (score 0):

**You forget to close your else if bracket.**